# how to sum table columns contains input fields using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a billing web application in laravel

I created a form  and a button (on click button call `addtoinvoice()` ) function, then it will add rows in table  and created input fields .
so i want to get sum of all `product_values[]` columns

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addtoinvoice()
{
  var products = document.getElementById("product");
  var productsvalue = products.options[products.selectedIndex].value;

  var client = document.getElementById("client");
  var clientvalue = client.options[client.selectedIndex].value;


  

  
//----verify product or client input is not nulll------------


  if(productsvalue == "")
  {
        alert("Please select an product");

  }else if(clientvalue==""){
        alert("Please select an client");


  }else
  {
        
  var index,table =  document.getElementById("products");

  //-----------Insert Rows 1 ---------------
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  

 //----------------insert Columns-----------------





 
  var product_name = row.insertCell(0);
  var product_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_input_tag.type = "text";
  product_input_tag.name="product_name[]";
  product_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  
  var product_name_value = document.getElementById("product");
  product_input_tag.value = product_name_value.options[product_name_value.selectedIndex].text;
  product_name.appendChild(product_input_tag);

  

  var product_description = row.insertCell(1);
  var product_description_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_description_input_tag.type = "text";
  product_description_input_tag.name="product_desciption[]";
  product_description_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_description_value = document.getElementById("pro_description");
  product_description_input_tag.value = product_description_value.value;
  product_description.appendChild(product_description_input_tag);

  


  var product_uom = row.insertCell(2);
  var product_uom_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_uom_input_tag.type = "text";
  product_uom_input_tag.name="product_uom[]";
  product_uom_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_uom_value = document.getElementById("uom");
  product_uom_input_tag.value = product_uom_value.value;
  product_uom.appendChild(product_uom_input_tag);

  


  var product_qty = row.insertCell(3);
  var product_qty_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_qty_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_qty_input_tag.name="product_qty[]";
  product_qty_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_qty_value = document.getElementById("qty");
  product_qty_input_tag.value = product_qty_value.value;
  product_qty.appendChild(product_qty_input_tag);

  



  var product_unitprice = row.insertCell(4);
  var product_unitprice_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_unitprice_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_unitprice_input_tag.name="product_uniprice[]";
  product_unitprice_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_unitprice_value = document.getElementById("unit_price");
  product_unitprice_input_tag.value = product_unitprice_value.value;
  product_unitprice.appendChild(product_unitprice_input_tag);

  


  var product_discount = row.insertCell(5);
  var product_discount_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_discount_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_discount_input_tag.name="product_discount[]";
  product_discount_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_discount_value = document.getElementById("discount");
  product_discount_input_tag.value = product_discount_value.value;
  var discount = product_discount_value.value;
  product_discount.appendChild(product_discount_input_tag);



  var product_value = row.insertCell(6);
  var product_value_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_value_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_value_input_tag.name="product_value[]";
  product_value_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  var original = (product_unitprice_value.value)*(product_qty_value.value);
  var newdiscount = (original/100)*discount;
  var total_discount = original-newdiscount;
  var result = Math.round(total_discount*100)/100;
  product_value_input_tag.value = result;
  product_value.appendChild(product_value_input_tag);



  var product_cgst = row.insertCell(7);
  var product_cgst_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_cgst_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_cgst_input_tag.name="product_cgst[]";
  product_cgst_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  product_cgst_input_tag.value = 0;
  product_cgst.appendChild(product_cgst_input_tag);


  var product_sgst = row.insertCell(8);
  var product_sgst_input_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_sgst_input_tag.type = "number";
  product_sgst_input_tag.name="product_cgst[]";
  product_sgst_input_tag.readOnly=true;
  product_sgst_input_tag.value = 0;
  product_sgst.appendChild(product_sgst_input_tag);



  var product_igst = row.insertCell(9);
  var product_igst_tag = document.createElement("input");
  product_igst_tag.type = "text";
  product_igst_tag.name="product_igst[]";
  product_igst_tag.readOnly=true;
  var product_igst_value = document.getElementById("tax");
  var igst = product_igst_value.options[product_igst_value.selectedIndex].value;
  var tax = (total_discount/100)*igst;
  product_igst_tag.value = Math.round(tax*100)/100;
  product_igst.appendChild(product_igst_tag);


  var remove_row = row.insertCell(10);
  var product_remove = document.createElement("span");
  product_remove.className="btn btn-danger";

  var button_name = document.createTextNode("Remove");
  product_remove.appendChild(button_name);
  remove_row.appendChild(product_remove);



//------------Cells Insert End----------------





//--------Remove Rows start----------



  for(var i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++)
  {

        table.rows[i].cells[10].onclick = function()
        {
              var c = confirm("do you want to remove this product ?");
              if(c == true)
              {
                    index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                    table.deleteRow(index);

              }
              
             
        }



   }



 

//-------Remove Rows End-------------


//----------Calculate All sums subtotal,discount,tax etc..------------











 





  



    }

}
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you have an array of product_values ?

Comment: @OskarZanota yes product_value[]

Comment: `product_values` or `product_value` ?